# Alternative to sql NOT IN?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, subquery

I am trying to make a materialized view in Oracle (I am a newbie, btw). For some reason, it doesn't like the presence of sub-query in it. I've been trying to use LEFT OUTER JOIN instead, but it's returning different data set now.

Put simply, here's the code I'm trying to modify:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 ros, table2 bal, table3 flx
WHERE  flx.name = 'XXX'
       AND flx.value = bal.value
       AND NVL (ros.ret, 'D') = Nvl (flx.attr16, 'D')
       AND ros.value = bal.segment3
       AND ros.type IN ( 'AL', 'AS', 'PL' )
       AND bal.period = 13
       AND bal.code NOT IN (SELECT bal1.code
                            FROM   table2 bal1
                            WHERE  bal1.value = flx.value
                                   AND bal1.segment3 = ros.value
                                   AND bal1.flag = bal.flag
                                   AND bal1.period = 12
                                   AND bal1.year = bal.year)
```

And here's one of my attempt:

```
SELECT  *      
FROM   table1 ros, table2 bal, table3 flx
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 bal1
            ON bal.code = bal1.code      
WHERE  bal1.code is null
       AND bal1.segment3 = ros.value
       AND bal.segment3 = ros.value
       AND bal1.flag = bal.flag
       AND bal1.year = bal.year
       AND flx.name = 'XXX'
       AND flx.value = bal.value
       AND bal1.value = flx.value
       AND bal1.period_num = 12
       AND NVL (ros.type, 'D') = NVL (flx.attr16, 'D')
       AND ros.value = bal.segment3
       AND ros.type IN ( 'AL', 'AS', 'PL' )
       AND bal.period = 13;
```

This drives me nuts! Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: Edited your tags. 'not' and 'in' are not useful tags.

Comment: Could you also please post table structures and what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to avoid the subquery. I jumped on google and read some article saying that LEFT OUTER JOIN is the alternative of NOT IN.

Answer (score 1):

Try `NOT EXISTS` insted of `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM   
  table1 ros
  INNER JOIN table2 bal ON ros.value = bal.segment3
  INNER JOIN table3 flx ON flx.value = bal.value AND NVL(ros.ret, 'D') = Nvl(flx.attr16, 'D')
WHERE
  flx.name = 'XXX'
  AND ros.type IN ( 'AL', 'AS', 'PL' )
  AND bal.period = 13
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE
    code         = bal.code
    AND value    = flx.value
    AND segment3 = ros.value
    AND flag     = bal.flag
    AND period   = 12
    AND year     = bal.year
  )
```

BTW to make the sub-query fast, create a composite index on `table2` that contains all fields you use in the sub-query.

Comment: I'll try to use NOT EXIST - but I kinda doubt it though.. as the subquery presents still.. thx anyway

Comment: Note that the MV will not be capable of _fast refresh_ when `NOT EXISTS` is used.

Answer (score 0):

Something among these lines should work **with some assumptions**. It does an outer join on table2 and eliminates all the records from the result set which have been joined.

```
select tab.*
from (
  SELECT *
  FROM   table1 ros, table2 bal, table3 flx
  WHERE  flx.name = 'XXX'
         AND flx.value = bal.value
         AND NVL (ros.ret, 'D') = Nvl (flx.attr16, 'D')
         AND ros.value = bal.segment3
         AND ros.type IN ( 'AL', 'AS', 'PL' )
         AND bal.period = 13
) TAB,
table2 BAL1
       AND bal1.code(+) = tab.code
       AND bal1.value(+) = tab.value_flx
       AND bal1.segment3(+) = tab.value_ros
       AND bal1.flag(+) = tab.flag
       AND bal1.period(+) = 12
       AND bal1.year(+) = tab.year
       AND bal1.code is NULL
```

**EDITED** to conform the rule that you can outer join to only on one table